# Differences between WooCommerce price filters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price

First of all, thank you for your support all those years.

I am building a role-based pricing plugin for a client and I am having an existential crisis over filters WooCommerce uses for prices. I made this post in hope someone can explain this so someone in the future can find this post.

I managed to understand how filters for simple products work but I don't have an idea how equivalent filters for variable products work

**Simple products**

As from what I understood, you can override price, regular price, and sale price for simple products returning some value inside filters `woocommerce_product_get_price`, `woocommerce_product_get_regular_price`, and `woocommerce_product_get_sale_price`. Those filters will save provided data into $product object and you can easily access them later in `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter by using `$product->get_regular_price`

**Variable products**

Looks like variable products work differently. For example, they dont save overriden price to $product or $variation object and you cannot fetch overriden prices by calling `$variation->get_regular_price`.

As I understood, following filters change price of the product on add-to-cart variation select, and in the cart and do not save them in $variation object.

```
woocommerce_product_variation_get_price
woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price
woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price
```

I didnt manage to fully understand what following filters do. But when I turn them on loop price changes and product price changes but prices are removed from add-to-cart select and cart prices are not changed.

```
woocommerce_variation_prices_price
woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price
woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price
```